# error: cannot access AnimatedImage class file for com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.base.AnimatedImage not found

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm getting errors

> error: cannot access AnimatedImage
>
> class file for com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.base.AnimatedImage not found

On attempting to run https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android purely from source.
After checking Build Output, I see
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h24e.png).

I couldn't find anything mentioning com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.base.AnimatedImage, and can't manage to find what's wrong.

Edit: I actually managed to solve this. I was running a not matching version of the Android API to my connected android device.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually managed to solve this. I was running a not matching version of the Android API to my connected android device.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

add one more dependency

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:1.13.0'
```

then it works just fine