# Error in official WhatsApp Stickers example App

Tags: android, whatsapp, webp

I just found [this Project](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android) and was like. hey. why not trying to use it?

So. just downloaded it (i did NOT change anything!), opened Android Studio, ran it, and faced following.

> error: cannot access AnimatedImage class file for
>   com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.base.AnimatedImage not found

Then I tried to Google the issue, re-checked it, re-tried it, and finally end up here.

Do you have any idea on how to get this project working?

**I reached in an issue-ticket:**
https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/429#issue-414808090

Comment: you should create an issue on github. or make sure fresco is loaded correctly, it´s a remote dependency.

Comment: same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427681/error-cannot-access-animatedimage-class-file-for-com-facebook-imagepipeline-ani

Comment: Which version do you use of Fresco? post `build.gradle`

Comment: just the one available in the files on github (1.12.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: cannot access AnimatedImage class file for com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.base.AnimatedImage not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427681/error-cannot-access-animatedimage-class-file-for-com-facebook-imagepipeline-ani)

Answer (score 2):

just add this library in your build file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:1.13.0'
```

Note: The version of this library should be equal to other fresco libraries already present in your build file.

Comment: Its `implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:2.3.0'`